# Google Channel API - How to test it locally?

Tags: channel-api

I want to test my application which share messages between two users using google channel api, but I manage to see messages going only from one side to the other. 
is it because I'm opening 2 channels on the same machine? I am running the application on different browsers (Chrome and IE) and each one logged in with a different user name? shouldn't that be enough?

Any suggestion on how to test my application on a single PC, or must I connect another PC for such application?

Thanks
Muky.

Comment: Don't know how, but I manage to work it with Chrome and FF. I guess it's an IE issue on debugger mode.

Answer (score 1):

You surely can test Google Channel API on a single machine. (I've done it, it works). Note that, when I run it on my local machine, I see the browser makes continuous requests (polling) although, when I upload it to Google App Engine, I only see push notifications. (You can check out the requests using Firebug in Firefox - in the NET tab). As far as I understand, Channel API is simulated in local mode using polling whereas, when uploaded to Google App Engine, they make use of Comet (not polling, rather long-lived requests).

I don't think your case was a browser issue. Each logged in user should open one channel. Then when you want to send a message to every users, you should send a message to each id that's logged in.